# Calendar giving HOUR and MINUTE without leading zero - Android

Tags: android, calendar

I know a lot of tutorials there about calendar giving minute and hours without leading zero. But those doesnt work for my codes. Can someone help me how to do this base on my codes? Calendar.MINUTE is not showing the zero integer whenever the minite is from 0-9.

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  String am_pm, hour;
  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);

  if(cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
      am_pm = "AM";
      else
      am_pm = "PM"; 

tv.setText(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
  tv2.setText(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + am_pm);
tv3.setText("Offered");
```

Comment: They are just `int`s and not formatted strings. If you need to format a date, use `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use DateFormat or Simple way to do this is

```
String month=String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String day=String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
String year=String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
tv.setText( month+ "-" + day + "-" +year );
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Its working. A checked for your answer! But when HOUR is 12:00, I get 00:00? How can I make it to 12:00?

Comment: Wow thanks! Its working. A checked for your answer! But when HOUR is 12:00, I get 00:00? How can I make it to 12:00?

Comment: Don't forget to add 1 for months: `String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormat for text output.

For example:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
String am_pm, hour;
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);

Date date = cal.getTime();

DateFormat[] formats = new DateFormat[] {
    DateFormat.getDateInstance(),
    DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(),
    DateFormat.getTimeInstance(),
};
for (DateFormat df : formats) {
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
}
```